# How to make TFS deploy ASP.net Web App after successful build?

Tags: deployment, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am trying to set up one of my ASP.net projects for continuous integration with TFS.  Amongst my requirements, I need to set up TFS so that each time there is a successful build with passing tests, the ASP.net code should be deployed to my development web server.

What I have done so far is I have set up a private agent behind my firewall (so that the agent has a "line of sight" to the development web server.  I've set up a build that runs all unit tests, and I have the gated check-in setup up so that the build is rejected if the tests don't pass.

I can see that the build artifact is created by the agent, but I am stuck with trying to figure out how to actually deploy the artifact to the development web server.

I have my publish profiles in Visual Studio, but I'm guessing that those are useless in TFS.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/create-deploy-releases

Comment: Yes, I read that document you linked.  It doesn't so much as tell me how to specify what server I want to deploy to!

Comment: It's just like creating a build: Compose a deployment out of the available tasks. If a task doesn't exist to do what you want, write your own or find something on the marketplace that does it. This question is too broad as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to below link and follow the steps mentioned in the article to  deploy the artifact to the web server:

- [End to End Walkthrough: Deploying Web Applications Using Team Build
  and Release Management](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/end-to-end-walkthrough-deploying-web-applications-using-team-build-and-release-management)
- [Deploy to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Release Management IIS Web Deployment
  vnext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monub/2016/01/20/visual-studio-team-services-release-management-iis-web-deployment-vnext/)

---

For the publish profiles, you can pass parameters into MSBuild during the building in TFS, eg : `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=MyProfile`

Reference below threads to use the `Publish Profiles`:

- [TFS 2017 publish with PublishProfile](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=m1AmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=TFS%202017%20publish%20with%20PublishProfile&source=bl&ots=6KclVhWmEO&sig=VFXcbx58mV1Qn8YY6Kb_7BLxG98&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY3bfi4MLXAhUFkJQKHSfeD3k4ChDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=TFS%202017%20publish%20with%20PublishProfile&f=false)
- [Build and Deploy a Web Application with TFS 2017 using Web Deploy Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985427/build-and-deploy-a-web-application-with-tfs-2017-using-web-deploy-package)