# TFS 2015 Release management: Specify name of the application inside a specific App Pool as the website name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs, iis-7.5, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to do a web deploy of a MVC application. I added Copy files to remote machine, IIS management and IIS web deployment.

I need to deploy it to an application inside App pool. 
Going through the video URL below 
https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=tfs-visual-studio-2015-implementing-continuous-delivery&author=marcel-devries&name=tfs-visual-studio-2015-implementing-continuous-delivery-m4&clip=4&mode=live.
The author ask's to specify the website name. In my case the website name is the application name in the app pool.

How do I specify the application name under an app pool in website name parameter of IIS management.

[image: Release management screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description the website name shoule be the application name, so just put the application name as the website name parameter.

Please read the [Overview and parameters instruction](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/README_IISAppMgmt.md) for the `WinRM - IIS Web App Management` task .  And this [Deploy: IIS Web App Manage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage)

Besides, you can also use the MSBuild with arguments to deploy the application, refer to below links to do that:

- [Deploying application in a remote and local machine with TFS 2015
  vNext](http://executeautomation.com/blog/deploying-application-in-a-remote-and-local-machine-with-tfs-2015-vnext/)
- [An ASP.NET MVC Site That’s Easy to Deploy from a TFS Build](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/08/an-asp-net-mvc-site-thats-easy-to-deploy-from-a-tfs-build/)
- [Build and Deploy a Web Application with TFS 2017 using Web Deploy Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985427/build-and-deploy-a-web-application-with-tfs-2017-using-web-deploy-package)

---

**UPDATE:**

If you already have a website and you want to deploy your Application under the website. Then you just need to use the `IIS Web App Deploy` step. The `Web App Management` step is not needed.

Just try `websitename\appname` as the Website name parameter in `IIS Web App Deploy` step. See [Parameters for IIS Application configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage#parameters-for-iis-application-configuration)

Comment: when I try to put application name it creates a new website at the server

Comment: @NandanA That's the expected behavior, just see the **Pre-requisites for the task**  ---- IIS Web Server:
`There should be a IIS web server already installed and configured on the pre-existing machines or virtual machines. The task creates or updates websites and application pools, and deploys IIS web applications but does not install or configure IIS web server on the machines.` If no site there it will create a new one, and next time it will update the existing site.

Comment: @Nandan A Have you resolved the issue? please check if  the updated answer helps.

Comment: thanks for helping out. I just needed web deploy step